# Why is there an outline on my image in HTML?I'm trying

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put this settings/gear icon on the same line as a subheading in HTML but the icon/image has a weird outline around it that I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of.

Here is an image

[image: See how the icon has an outline around it]

Here is the HTML code for it

`<div class="sidenavSubTitleVector">Languages<img class="languagesIconGear"></div>`

```
Here is the CSS code for it

.languagesIconGear {
  background: transparent url("Images/gearIcon.svg") no-repeat center top;
  border: 0;
  min-height: 16px;
  min-width: 16px;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: When this is a part of the image, you should edit that image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invalid HTML syntax, make sure to stick to HTML standards to avoid such issues in the future.

If you specify an image you also need to provide a `src` attribute. If you don't you will end up with an "img-not-found" state which results in your rendering bug.

To fix this, use this HTML:

`<h3 class="sidenavSubTitleVector">Languages<img class="languagesIconGear" src="Images/gearIcon.svg" alt="settings"></h3>`

An image also needs an `alt` attribute to describe it. As an example I used settings, since I guess this gear icon should open some settings.

Note, I also updated your title to an actual title of level 3:  `<h3>` The level 3 is just guesswork on my part, use the appropriate level for your structure.